# Mysql how to select in same tables with join

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
JOIN users AS parent
ON parent.username = 'Joe'
WHERE users.ip = parent.ip;
```

It's correct ?

How to select in same table like:

```
SELECT article.* FROM article
JOIN users
ON users.username = 'Joe' OR users.ip = (????? maybe users.ip)
WHERE article.owner = users.username;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to swap the content of your ON and WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM article
JOIN users
ON article.owner = users.username 
WHERE users.username = 'Joe' OR users.ip = (????? maybe users.ip);
```

The ON clause determines according to which condition the two tables are joined

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.